# Can a periodic function be represented with roots $= x^2$ where $x$ is an element of the integers?

Tags: periodic-functions

I only want the roots of the function to equal whole squares. So the function $\sin(\pi\times x)$ would not work, the roots can only be whole square numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \cases{\sin(\pi\sqrt{x}),& $x\ge 0$\cr x, & $x < 0$}$$
$$f(x) = 0\iff x\ge0, \sin(\pi\sqrt{x}) = 0\iff x\ge0,\pi\sqrt{x} = k\pi, k\in\Bbb Z\iff x = k^2, k\in\Bbb Z.$$
But the condition of periodicity is impossible.

Comment: Can you explain this, I just need to have a function who's roots are only whole numbers squared, I need it as a tool for something, then I've solved the problem.

Comment: @Jack, see the edit.